# Frama-C: Replacing a Cil Term in a Cil Predicate

Tags: c, frama-c

Using the `Cil_datatypes` module defined in the Frama-C API, I am trying to replace a term (Cil_datatype) with a new term in a predicate (Cil_datatype).
To do that I need to map a predicate with a function that when it finds the term (or terms) replaces it there. How do you map over a predicate to replace a term?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you are looking for the visitor mechanism described in section 4.16 of [the plugin development guide](http://frama-c.com/download/plugin-development-guide-Neon-20140301.pdf). Basically, you inherit from the `Visitor.frama_c_copy` or `Visitor.frama_c_inplace` class and redefines the `vterm` method so that it returns the modified term where needed. To initiate the visit, you then can call `Visitor.visitFramacIdPredicate` (or a similar function depending on the exact type of the predicate) with an instance of your class and the predicate to modify.

Note that if you do in-place modifications, your transformations might interfere with the annotation management done by the Frama-C kernel. It is thus better let `Visitor.frama_c_copy` perform a deep copy of the predicate.

Comment: thank you for the answer, it was very helpful, but i'am having some problems with the visit actions, and getting some fatal warnings about Cil.visitAction: "It is not visible in the current scope, and will not be selected if the type becomes unknown.". I will edit my original question to add this extra information.

Comment: Since `visitAction` is defined in the `Cil` module, you have to either `open Cil` at the beginning of your file, or use fully qualified names such as `Cil.ChangeDoChildrenPost` instead of `ChangeDoChildrenPost`.